# Android Emulator system images: release notes? Google API version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

Android Studio notified me that there are updates (revisions) to several AVD system images. I tried Google to find out what new features/fixes these updates bring but I could not find any release notes.

Anybody got a link? Or a way to find out which Google API version they use?

Comment: I have never seen release notes about AVD images. "Or a way to find out which Google API version they use?" -- well, you can look at the "Google Play services" app's version info in Settings > Apps. I don't know how well that maps to anything that would be useful for you.

Comment: "Look in Settings > Apps". Why didn't I think of that? It is useful for me because now I know the emulator runs Google Play services 10.0.84. This means I can now compile my app against the latest Google Play API: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1' without the emulator complaining that I should update to the latest version of Google Play services (which I cannot do). Thanks @CommonsWare! If you write your comment in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried Google to find out what new features/fixes these updates bring but I could not find any release notes.

I have never seen release notes for the emulator images. I cannot rule out that there are some notes floating around somewhere, but I suspect that there are none.

> Or a way to find out which Google API version they use?

You can find out what version of the Play Services Framework exists on an emulator (or device) via Settings > Apps, as to some extent, Play Services is just an app.